# Is it possible to make two models embed each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, database-relations

Say there are two models: Host and Event. Each event has exactly one host, but the same person may be hosting several events. The event may be created without knowing who will be hosting it, so `embedded_in` relation won't work since it requires the host to be specified upon creation. Is it possible to define the structure as follows:

```
class Host
   include Mongoid::Document
   embeds_many :events
end

class Event
   include Mongoid::Document
   embeds_one :host
end
```

I have tried doing that but `embeds_one` and `embeds_many` don't seem to create corresponding fields. Moreover, when I tried assigning a host to the event I got `NoMethodError: undefined method "first" for Event object`.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

I know I can use 'has_many' and `belongs_to' relations. But I would like to have the whole host document stored in the event and not just his ID.

Comment: No, it won't work that way. You cannot have `embeds_many` association in both models for each other. If you intend to store `host` embedded inside an `event`, this will result in duplicate entries. If multiple events are hosted by a single host, then all of those `events` will embed their own `host` record. Instead you should be using `has_many` relationship here. `Event` `belongs_to` a `Host`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yeah, that's what I thought. Just hoped there is some workaround. Thank you